# Rails assets loading twice in development; creates strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I'm working on a [rails app](https://github.com/duhaime/chalkboard) and am seeing strange behavior that I believe is caused by rails assets loading multiple times in development.

I'm working in Chrome, and had the `Developer Tools -> Network -> "disable cache"` checkbox marked, which made js and css assets load only once and made everything work as expected/desired.

When I unchecked the `"disable cache"` box, however, assets started to load multiple times, and typeahead breaks, throwing: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function`.

Steps to reproduce:

```
git clone https://github.com/duhaime/chalkboard.git
cd chalkboard
rake sunspot:solr:start
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed
rake sunspot:solr:reindex
rails s
# visit localhost:3000 and enable/disable cache (then refresh) in Chrome
```

I believe it's possible to resolve this error by disabling caching from within Rails (as opposed to the browser client), but I wanted to ask if there is a proper way to resolve this situation without disabling caching. I've read through many of the other SO threads on this question, but haven't found a workable solution. I would be very grateful for any advice others can provide on this question!

Comment: The only time I've had rails javascript double-loading, it was because there was a compiled (but not digest-stamped) version of `application.js` sitting in `public/assets`. It would be worth deleting `public/assets/application.js` if it exists, it may fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks @robomc; I don't have a `public/assets` directory :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason typeahead was failing was because I was importing it via `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require twitter/typeahead
//= require_tree .
```

and I was using `<%= javascript_include_tag 'typeahead' %>`. To make matters worse, the typeahead include calls was importing `typeahead.bundle.js` version 0.11.1, and I had gem installed `twitter-bootstrap-rails` version 0.10.5.

I removed all of the `<%= javascript_include_tag '{package}' %>`, removed the `typeahead.bundle.js` file from my `/assets` directory, and the `$(...).typeahead is not a function` error has gone away. I'll leave this question here in case it will help others.